# Concatenating LPCSTR variable and literal?

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a `LPCSTR` variable `name` and I want to use it in `MessageBoxA(NULL,name,"pop up",MB_OK);`
where I want name to hold value `name+" is X"`. For example name has value  `John` so I am expecting output on Message Box as "`John is X"`.
Can anyone help me with this?

I tried using  `std::(string(name)+string(" is X")).c_str();`
since I am using  `MessageBoxA` and need to concatenate `LPCSTR`.

I know how to use it for `MessageBoxW` which takes argument `LPCWSTR`.
I have used this way before.

```
    wchar_t waCoord[20];
    wsprintf(waCoord, _T("(%i,%i)"),x , y);
    MessageBox(hWnd, waCoord, _T(" click"), MB_OK);
```

Comment: Off topic: "_I know how to use it for `MessageBox` which takes argument `LPCWSTR`._" Technically, there is no function `MessageBox`. There are `MessageBoxA`, and `MessageBoxW`, and `MessageBox` is a `#define` to either of those two, depending on whether `UNICODE` macro is set in your environment.

Comment: Thanks but can you help me with my question?

Comment: It's hard to know what your question is. It seems weird that you would want to call `MessageBoxA` at all in 2020. But if you do, why would you be using `wchar_t`?

Comment: If you need to support both ANSI and Unicode builds, you can use the [TCHAR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/working-with-strings#tchars) type and corresponding functions.Basically you use `_tcsXXX()` functions instead of the corresponding `strXXX()` or `wcsXXX()` functions. And `_tsprintf()` instead of `sprintf()` or `swprintf()`.

Comment: @rveerd Nobody needs both ANSI and Unicode builds these days, though.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I am working on Legacy Code so I have to use it I am not using `wchar_t` I said  I know how to concatenate and how I do i mentioned in question.

Comment: "I am not using `wchar_t`" Well, the code in the question says otherwise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because answers to it aren't useful to anyone.

Comment: @Nurav "*I know how to use it for MessageBoxW*" - then you already know how to do it for `MessageBoxA()`, too.  Simply change `wchar_t` to `char`, and `wsprintf()` to `wsprintfA()` (or equivalent), eg: `char waCoord[20]; wsprintfA(waCoord, "(%i,%i)", x, y); MessageBoxA(hWnd, waCoord, " click", MB_OK);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `string` from the `LPCSTR` and then add `" is X"` to it.

Here's an example putting the result as both caption and text in the `MessageBoxA`:

```
#include <string>

void makebox(LPCSTR name) {
    std::string res(name);
    res += " is X";
    ::MessageBoxA(nullptr, res.c_str(), res.c_str(), MB_OK);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The simpliest options is to convert the `LPCSTR` to a `std::string`, then you can append to it as needed, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

LPCSTR name = ...;

MessageBoxA(NULL, (std::string(name) + " is X").c_str(), "pop up", MB_OK);
```

Another option is to use a `std::ostringstream`, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

LPCSTR name = ...;

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << name << " is X";
MessageBoxA(NULL, oss.str().c_str(), "pop up", MB_OK);
```

Answer (score 0):

`std::(string(name)+string(" is X"))`

That's a bit weird. `std::` is a namespace qualification, and it only applies to the name directly following it. You can't say `std::(X,Y,Z)` and have that `std::` apply to all of X,Y and Z.

The idea itself is good. `(std::string(name) + std::string(" is X")).c_str()` will work as intended.

Comment: You don't need the second `std::string` construction, since `std::string` has an `operator+` for `const char*` data, eg: `(std::string(name) + " is X").c_str()`